# How to use a field in TypeScript object as a value of another field?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am creating a const as below.

```js
1 const result = {
2  name : input.name,
3  events : function1(input.events),
4  status : function2(events),
5 }
```

But at line 4, I am getting the following error.

```
TS2552: Cannot find name 'events'.
```

How can I use the **events** field set at line 3 as an input parameter to function2 at line 4?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot refer to a field of an object literal until *after* you have finished creating that object.

So to use the same value twice in an object literal, you need to have a reference to that value before hand.

There are lots of ways to "have a reference" to a value, but in this case you could simply put it into a local variable first.

For example:

```
const events = function1(input.events)
const result = {
  name: input.name,
  events, // shorthand for `events: events`
  status: function2(events)
}
```